# Generic Interface implementation with subclass type

Tags: java, generics, interface, wildcard

Processor interface:

```
public interface Processor<T> {

    public void process(T request);

    public Class<T> getRequestType();
}
```

Processor implementation:

```
public class TextProcessor extends BaseProcessor implements Processor<TextRequest> {

@Override
public void process(TextRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public Class<TextRequest> getRequestType() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return TextRequest.class;
}
```

}

Request class:

```
public class Request {
    private long id;

    ...
}
```

TextRequest

```
public class TextRequest extends Request {
    String text;
    ...
}
```

Main class:

```
private Map<String, Processor<? extends Request>> processors;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Processor<?> processor = processors.get("proc name");
    Request request = objectMapper.readValue(json, processor.getRequestType());

    processor.process(request);
}
```

I am getting compilation error in the `process` call.

```
The method process(capture#10-of ?) in the type Processor<capture#10-of ?> is not applicable
for the arguments (Request)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got

```
Processor<?> processor = ...;
Request request = ...;
processor.process(request);
```

but `process` is declared as

```
public void process(T request);
```

`Request` cannot be guaranteed to be a subtype of `T`, therefore it will not compile.

You need to change `Request` to the correct type.

First of all you need need to return the right type of class.

```
public Class<?> getRequestType();
```

becomes

```
public Class<T> getRequestType();
```

(**Edit:** This has now been modified in the original question.)

Then we need to read an request object of the correct type. For any particular object `?` here will refer to a particular type. And we can capture that by introducing a new method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doProcess(processors.get("proc name"));
}
private static <T> void doProcess(Processor<T> processor) {
    T request = objectMapper.readValue(json, processor.getRequestType());
    processor.process(request);
}
```

Comment: The invoker of `process` only has the processor object and the request type it expects.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA generics are checked at compile time.

So when you write `Processor<?> processor = processors.get("proc name");` we don't know how to validate request against `?`.

If you can accept this - try with non-generic version of processor:

```java
Processor processor = new TextProcessor();
```

Otherwise maybe add some constraints for `Processor` interface (`void process(Request request);`)?

Comment: implementation has to be created dynamically based on the name of the request.

Answer (score 0):

The processor you get in `Processor<?> processor = processors.get("proc name");` is parameterized of unknown type which has nothing common with the type in `processor.getRequestType()`. It is unclear to me what benefit generics bring to you in this case. It seem you don't have to know what is concrete `Request` subtype in main function so everything could be rewritten without generics. The root cause of problem is the `processors` map where all processors are in one bunch.

I can imagine benefits of generics for example when the processor map would be implemented as heterogenous map with some correlation between key type and value type. The `Processor.getRequestType` would then have to be parametrized by type `T` too, then you could use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Processor<TextRequest> processor = processors.get(TextRequest.class);
    TextRequest request = objectMapper.readValue(json, processor.getRequestType());
    processor.process(request);
}
```

Comment: Processor has to be fetched from the map using the name of the request. And processor will tell me the type of request it expects. So everything is dynamic. Is there a way to achieve this using generics?

Comment: @cppcoder If you must choose processor by `name` (rather than other type-aware information as I suggested), you don't have other possibility than to represent processor as wildcard type. Actual type is not known at compile time. Then Tom Hawtin's answer does the job for you - it uses wildcard trick described by Angelika Langer here http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ304 . In a nutshell, it says "no matter what type is processor parameterized of, in helper method must processor and request type match".